# removing selected item from dropdown but displaying it as selected

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a drop down like below which displays 10,20,30,40

```
<select>
 <OPTION value="10" label="10"> 10 </OPTION>
 <OPTION value="20" label="20"> 20 </OPTION>
 <OPTION value="30" label="30"> 30 </OPTION>
 <OPTION value="40" label="40"> 40 </OPTION>
</select>
```

It will display 10 as selected and when we click on dropdown, 10,20,30,40.

If 20 is selected, It will display 10 as selected and when we click on dropdown, 10,20,30,40.

Now I have to implement like, if 20 is selected, display it as selected, but in dropdown, display only 10,30,40. 20 should be displayed only in selected place.

Is there any way to implement this functionality?

Comment: erm, isn't that like defying the purpose of select box?

Comment: Yes it is possible, no don't do it. There's too much to go wrong and you will potentially confuse your users as it goes against the way everything like this works. For the record though this is client side and nothing to do with PHP, retagging as Javascript.

Comment: ya i know.... that's why i put this question here. Just to confirm whether there is any way to do it.

Comment: @RiksAndroid: See my answer it outlines one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML does not offer such an input element that is able to do so.

You might be able with CSS using the attribute selector on the `selected` attribute of `<OPTION>` and set display to none. That *might* trick the browser.

Comment: @RiksAndroid: Try it, sure. I can tell you it works. However we will then see if that is really what you wanted to ask for.

Comment: @RiksAndroid: I created a fiddle, there are more variations possible, those are the four ones I can see: http://jsfiddle.net/m9pA6/3/ - maybe it's of use.

Comment: Thank's a lot dude. I had implemented like this only as suggested by you. Thank's again